# Is there way to create a text log file of files in a directory in Windows 10?

Tags: batch, zip, 7-zip

I am 7zip-ing files for archiving, this presents a problem of not being able to find a file (in those zipped files) if I search in windows. However, if I could create a text file, that lists all the files in that zip file, which will be stored in the same folder, it would make it easier as I could index the contents as well.

At the moment, I use a BAT file to automate the zippping

```
for /d %%X in (*) do "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "%%X.7z" "%%X\" -mx=9
```

I'm not sure if this BAT can be edited to add the creation of text file as well.

Comment: Try adding the 7z command to list the file in your do loop. Your code will be like: ```for /d %%X in (*) do (
"c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "%%X.7z" "%%X\" -mx=9
"c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" l "%%X.7z" >> log.txt
)```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm not sure if this BAT can be edited to add the creation of text file as well.

Assuming you wanted this all on one line, you could try adding a second command with `&` or `&&` e.g. `dir /b /s /a:-d "%%X" >> %%X.txt`:

```
for /d %%X in (*) do "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "%%X.7z" "%%X\" -mx=9 & dir /b /s /a:-d "%%X" >> %%X.txt
```

This would zip the folder, then create a `.txt` file with the same name as each processed folder (`%%X`). This text file would contain the full path of each file under that folder/zip file (including in subfolders).

---

*References*

*[dir](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) (SS64)*

*[What does “&&” do in this batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28889954/what-does-do-in-this-batch-file) (Stack Overflow)*

Comment: Everytime I run this on multiple folders, it sets of my AntiVirus (avast) as it wants to delete the first text file created. I can't create an exception as each time the bat file will be in a different folder, when I allow the app and rerun it works fine.